# why does keras model.predict only return one probability?How can I output all probabilities of all the classes?

Tags: python, keras

I'm working on a classification problem. The dataset has 9 classes, so I want to get the probabilities of 9 classes, but the model.predict() in keras looks like only output the biggest one. I think the shape of yprobs should be (3014,9), then I can get the log_loss() work. hoping for some help! Thanks!!

'''model code'''

```
class AdaBNModel:

def __init__(self, nfeatures=50, arch=[8, 'abn', 'act'], activations='relu',
             droprate=0.0, noise=0.0, optimizer=None, val_data=None,
             validate_every=1, epochs=5000, batch_size=128, verbose=False):

    self.epochs = epochs
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.noise = noise
    self.verbose = verbose

    self.validate_every = validate_every
    if val_data is None:
        self.validate_every = 0
        self.Xval = None
        self.yval = None
    else:
        self.Xval = val_data[0]
        self.yval = val_data[1]

    self._build_model(arch, activations, nfeatures, droprate, noise, optimizer) 

def _build_model(self, arch, activations, nfeatures, droprate, noise, optimizer):

    self.layers = [Input(shape=(nfeatures,))]

    for i, nunits in enumerate(arch):

        if isinstance(nunits, int):
            self.layers += [Dense(nunits, activation='linear')(self.layers[-1])]

        elif nunits == 'noise':
            self.layers += [GaussianNoise(noise)(self.layers[-1])]

        elif nunits == 'bn':
            self.layers += [BatchNormalization()(self.layers[-1])]

        elif nunits == 'abn':
            self.layers += [AdaBN()(self.layers[-1])]

        elif nunits == 'drop':
            self.layers += [Dropout(droprate)(self.layers[-1])]

        elif nunits == 'act':
            if activations == 'prelu':
                self.layers += [PReLU()(self.layers[-1])]
            elif activations == 'elu':
                self.layers += [ELU()(self.layers[-1])]
            elif activations == 'leakyrelu':
                self.layers += [LeakyReLU()(self.layers[-1])]
            else:
                self.layers += [Activation(activations)(self.layers[-1])]

        else:
            print('Unrecognised layer {}, type: {}'.format(nunits, type(nunits)))

    self.layers += [Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(self.layers[-1])]

    self.model = Model(self.layers[0], self.layers[-1])
    self.model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)

def _fit(self, Xs, ys, Xt, yt, domains, Xval=None, yval=None, epochs=None, batch_size=None, verbose=None):

    if epochs is None: epochs = self.epochs
    if batch_size is None: batch_size = self.batch_size
    if Xval is None: 
        Xval = self.Xval
        yval = self.yval
    if verbose is None: verbose = self.verbose

    # batch generator that ensures that samples are always from the same domain
    S_batches = domain_batch_gen(Xs, ys, domains, batch_size=batch_size)

    # self.history = {'source_loss': [], 'target_loss': [], 'val_loss': []}
    self.history = {'source_loss': [], 'target_loss': []}
    for i in range(epochs):
        Xsource, ysource = S_batches.__next__()
        self.model.fit(Xsource, ysource, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0) 

        #if self.validate_every > 0 and i % self.validate_every == 0:
        if True:
            if i == 0:
                print('Epoch  sloss tloss vloss')

            self.history['source_loss'] += [self.evaluate(Xs, ys)]
            self.history['target_loss'] += [self.evaluate(Xt, yt)]
            #self.history['val_loss'] += [self.evaluate(Xval, yval)]

            print('{:04d}  {:.5f} {:.5f}  '.format(i,
                                                         self.history['source_loss'][-1],
                                                         self.history['target_loss'][-1]))
            # print('{:04d}  {:.5f} {:.5f} {:.5f} '.format(i,
            #     self.history['source_loss'][-1], self.history['target_loss'][-1], self.history['val_loss'][-1]))


def fit(self, Xs, ys, Xt, yt, domains=None, Xval=None, yval=None, epochs=None, batch_size=None, verbose=None):

    if epochs is None: epochs = self.epochs
    if batch_size is None: batch_size = self.batch_size
    if Xval is None: 
        Xval = self.Xval
        yval = self.yval
    if verbose is None: verbose = self.verbose

    if domains is None: domains = np.ones_like(ys, dtype=int)
    self._fit(Xs, ys, Xt, yt, domains, Xval, yval, epochs, batch_size, verbose)         

def predict_proba(self, X, domains=None, batch_size=None):
    if batch_size is None: batch_size = self.batch_size
    if domains is None:
        return self.model.predict(X,batch_size,verbose=1)
    else:                               
        ypreds = np.zeros(X.shape[0])
        udomains = np.unique(domains)#[1]
        #print(udomains.shape)
        for i in range(udomains.shape[0]):
            idx = (domains == udomains[i])
            # print(idx)
            # print(idx.shape)  #(3014,)
            print('domain')
            thisX = X[idx]
            # print(thisX)
            # print(thisX.shape)    #(3014, 145)
            # ypreds[idx] = self.model.predict(thisX, batch_size=batch_size).flatten()
            ypreds[idx] = self.model.predict(thisX, batch_size=batch_size).flatten()

        return ypreds

def evaluate(self, X, y, domains=None, batch_size=None):
    #yprobs = self.predict_proba(X, domains, batch_size)
    yprobs = self.model.predict(X,batch_size,verbose=1)
    print(yprobs)
    print(yprobs.shape)#(3014,1)
    print(y.shape)     #(3014,)
    return log_loss(y, yprobs)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  32/3014 [..............................] - ETA: 1s
3014/3014 [==============================] - 0s 5us/step
[[0.99279547]**strong text**
  File "D:/cmWorks/AdaBN-1d/example_adabn.py", line 33, in <module>
    model.fit(Xs, ys, Xt, yt)
  File "D:\cmWorks\AdaBN-1d\adabn.py", line 124, in fit
    self._fit(Xs, ys, Xt, yt, domains, Xval, yval, epochs, batch_size, verbose)         
  File "D:\cmWorks\AdaBN-1d\adabn.py", line 103, in _fit
 [0.9899932 ]
    self.history['source_loss'] += [self.evaluate(Xs, ys)]
 [0.9922549 ]
  File "D:\cmWorks\AdaBN-1d\adabn.py", line 154, in evaluate
    return log_loss(y, yprobs)
 ...
 [0.9604445 ]
 [0.9100603 ]
 [0.95761013]]
(3014, 1)
(3014,)
[8. 8. 8. ... 6. 6. 6.]
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\keras\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 1809, in log_loss
    lb.classes_))
ValueError: y_true and y_pred contain different number of classes 9, 2. Please provide the true labels explicitly through the labels argument. Classes found in y_true: [0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8.]
```

Comment: What makes you think it outputs a single probability? Show some of the complete output, from what I see there are multiple probabilities there. And more importantly, include the model code to see if there is any issue there.

Comment: I think the shape of yprobs should be (3014,9) and the model code as follow:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Occam's razor is always your best initial debugging tool, look at this line for the last layer of your model:

```
self.layers += [Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(self.layers[-1])]
```

Your model only has one output neuron, not nine as it should be for 9 classes. This is why keras predicts only one probability per sample.

Also note that for multi-class classification you should use a `softmax` activation at the last layer, unless you want to do multi-label classification, for which `sigmoid` is used.